# g++ warning about missing imlementation of pure virtual destructor

Tags: c++, g++

In CentOS 6.5, I have a class `List` like:

```
// list.hpp

namespace foo
{
    class List
    {
    public:
        virtual int reserveMem ( int size) = 0;
        virtual int Insert ( int val) = 0;
        virtual int Find ( int val) = 0;
        virtual bool Empty() = 0;
    };
}
```

It's part of the source code of a shared library. And I can build the whole library without any error or warning messages with g++ (version 4.4.7). The compiling flags used are

> -g -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Werror

Then we have another app which just includes a header file which includes this header file and got:

> list.hpp:14: error: 'class List' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor

The warning message is valid. But g++ never complains about it when I build the library. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because you never created object of a List type, I would guess

Comment: Define a virtual destructor for your class and it will go away.  virtual ~List() {}

Comment: The title of your question is very misleading, the warning has nothing to do with pure virtual destructors

Answer (score 1):

The warning is controlled by the `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` option, which is not included in `-Wall` or `-Wextra`. Presumably you are using different warning options to build the app  and the library. Building the app seems to be done with `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` enabled, or maybe the `-Weffc++` option which includes `-Wnon-virtual-dtor`

I consider that warning to be annoying and unhelpful, the `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor` is much more useful because it only warns if you actually try to `delete` a `foo::List*`, and is included in `-Wall`